# How to add toggle fullscreen button into QDockWidget in PyQt4?

Tags: qt, pyqt, pyqt4, titlebar, qdockwidget

By default, there are two small buttons on the [QDockWidget](http://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt4/html/qdockwidget.html) toolbar: "detach" and "close".

How can I add a new button: "toggle fullscreen"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [QDockWidget.setTitleBarWidget](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qdockwidget.html#setTitleBarWidget) function can be used to replace the existing titlebar (including buttons) with a custom widget of your own.

However, it's not possible to use [QDockWidget.titleBarWidget](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qdockwidget.html#titleBarWidget) get a reference to the *default* titlebar widget and add extra buttons to it.